# How to detect active printer (the printer that is ready to print) in coldfusion

Tags: printing, coldfusion

This coldfusion file runs on a localhost server connected with printers.

I am able to get the list of printers installed on the computer with this:

```
<cfset ahja ="#GetPrinterList()#">
```

It outputs in a list format like PrinterA, PrinterB, Printer C.

Now, all this printers aren't going to be online. 
Is there away i can be able to get the list of printers that are ready to print(i.e connected to computer and online).

I want to output them in a select box, where the user can select only available printers (printers are switched on and connected to the computer).

PS: There is no default printer assigned to the computer.

I have searched the internet but aint getting what can help.

Comment: If you mean printers connected to the user's computer, you can't.

Comment: @DanBracuk So what about getting the list of all the installed computers in a select box?  Not considering if they are online or offline. Thanks.

Comment: If you are trying to access information about printers on a *user's computer*, you are barking up the wrong tree. CF cannot access that information. It can only list printers connected to the CF *server*.

Comment: @Leigh  with the GetPrinterList() I was able to get the list of all printers installed on my computer.

Comment: Only because your computer *is* the CF server.

Comment: Coldfusion is Server side language, have no access to the client information (except the info sent by client to Server e.g in form of Cookies etc)

Comment: Ohhh.. So, is there anyway i can go about it maybe with another language or so?

Comment: @Leigh True! My computer is the CF server. So other computers connected to the server via a LAN won't be able to initiate the `<cfprint>` if the server isn't installed on it?

Comment: (Edit) No, it will run for any user that opens the .cfm script in their browser. However, it can only access printers connected to the *CF server*. Whether or not that is a problem all depends on what exactly you are trying to do (which is not clear).  Example: Say the CF server has access to three network printers: "A", "B" and "C". User "John" has a single printer connected to his computer: printer "M". Which printer are you trying to target when "John" loads the .cfm script?

Comment: @Leigh Sorry for my late reply. The network printers A, B or C

Comment: Then CFPrint would work. It prints to any printer connected to the *CF server*. However, AFAIK CF does not provide access to printer status. You will probably need to dip into java for that.